# httpClient oninit and ondestroy method

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient, angular-services

Is there any method like ngOnit and ngOnDestroy for httpClient method in Angular? Basically I am trying to show a spinner and hide the spinner on every httpClient call i make.

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need an interceptor:

Just create a Service that is responsible to set whether the Loader needs to show or hide. Set this value from your interceptor then:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { finalize } from "rxjs/operators";

import { LoaderService } from '../services/loader.service';

@Injectable()
export class LoaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(public loaderService: LoaderService) { }
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        this.loaderService.show();
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            finalize(() => this.loaderService.hide())
        );
    }
}
```

> Read [this article](https://firstclassjs.com/display-a-loader-on-every-http-request-using-interceptor-in-angular-7/) for more ref.